# mean of autoregressive process

Tags: mean, autoregressive

An autoregressive process of order p, AR(p), is of the form $x_t=\phi_1x_{t-1}+...+\phi_px_{t-p}+w_t$ where $x_t$ is stationary, i.e. $E[x_t]=\mu$ for all $t=0,1,2,...$,  and $w_t$ is white noise, i.e. $w_t\sim N(0,\sigma_w^2)$.

Hence,

$E[x_t]=E[\phi_1x_{t-1}+...+\phi_px_{t-p}+w_t]=\phi_1\mu+...+\phi_p\mu=\mu(\phi_1+...+\phi_p)$

this implies

$\mu=\mu(\phi_1 +...+\phi_p)$.

But this can only be true if $\mu=0$. If I understand this right this implies that the mean of a stationary AR(p) process always has to be zero.

So why do many books (e.g. "Time Series
Analysis and Its Applications" by Shumway and Stoffer) say that if $\mu\neq0$ we can replace $x_t$ by $x_t-\mu$ eventhough $\mu$ can't be zero?

Comment: Replacing $x_t$ by $x_t-\mu$ obviously works, so where is the issue?

Comment: Why would you replace $x_t$ by $x_t-\mu$ if $\mu$ is anyways allways zero ?

Comment: I mean it is not wrong just unnecessary. So why would you even consider the case where $\mu \neq 0$ if this case never happens?

Comment: Why couldn't the autoregressive parameters sum to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the definition you gave, you *assumed* that the expectation of the process is zero. You can transform a stationary AR(p) process where $E[x_t]\neq 0$ to have zero expectation by simply subtracting $\mu$. For these processes you will have

$$
x_t = c + \phi_1 x_{t-1}+ \dots + \phi_p x_{t-p} + w_t,
$$

where $c=\mu(1-\phi_1-\dots-\phi_p) $.